# Recognizing an marker image for AR

Tags: javascript, image-processing, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I have a problem which in my eyes is on the rather simple side of image recognition. I am trying to check if in a video a certain picture is shown. I only want to provide some kind of simple Picture, e.g a logo of a company or a simple shape. If this Picture is found in the video feed an action should be started.

I have no experience in image recognition but I find many libraries detecting whole objects and faces. Finding a given image should be done way more easily, or should it? I am trying to solve this problem in JS but any starting point would be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem requires specific object detection whose feature may vary a lot in natural scenes because of different view point, intensity, So you can try using SIFT, SURF for key point matching and object recognition. If the image features do not vary a lot you can achieve this feat with simple temple matching using [opencv.js](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/df0/tutorial_js_table_of_contents_imgproc.html)(JavaScript port of OpenCV library).
Also if the object of interest contains certain fixed color, you can filter the object using a predefined color range in HSV color model image as explained [here](http://ciphervision.com/Color-based-object-detection)

More robust solution: If you have good data-set of your object of interest, you can build a deep learning model for object detection using tensorflow and use it in JavaScript using [Tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/), though i have not tried this approach.

Comment: thank you very much. I was hoping to get an answer containing more magic, e.g. I give the program an Image and it is found rather instantly. I understand  that this is a complex topic but I hoped I had overseen something.

Best Regards